# Post installation of SSIS for existing SQL Server instance with different build versions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssis, installation

I would like to install SSIS into existing SQL Server 2014 Fail-over cluster instance with latest cumulative update 7 which was applied. I know how to do it but I want to know if consistency of versions between SSIS (from installation disc) and SQL Server 2014 (already updated) will be kept at the same latest server version (latest version is 12.0.2560).

In to detail, I mean I have latest CU7 update applied but I want to install SSIS from image where is first RTM version release 12.0.2000 but currently I have 12.0.2560 CU7 Server version which is newer. Will be there conflict of versions or SSIS has no impact which version of SQL Server is actually installed? I can also download image of SQL Server 2014 with SP1, but build version is higher than actual CU7 (SP1 is 12.0.4100 build version and CU7 with fixes 12.0.2560 build version). Reason why I don't want to install SP1 even when build version is higher has less fixed bugs than actual CU7.

So in result does post-installation of SSIS downgrade SQL Server version to which installation media contains or it will be self-upgraded to actual server installed version?

Comment: Does any of the fixes in CU7 not in SP1 really affect SSIS in your project? If not, there's no point in installing CU7.

Comment: There were issues in first release of SP1 with SSIS where Microsoft unpublished SP1 and after few weeks released new repaired SP1. I heard  Microsoft said that nowadays will not release any service packs just CU's, so that's why I don't want to install SP, because it doesn't permit install any CU update because of lower build number than SP has. I don't want to go in state where microsoft rolls CU's each month and SP1 will be just latest update without any future post-SP1 updates.

Comment: The issues with SP1 were just affecting the SP installer itself and not the fixes shipped with it. The rumors you're referring to just rumors. SP1 CU1 is already in the works and will be realeased shortly.

Comment: Thank you for information about SP1 CU1. Maybe I'll apply SP1 but It would be interesting to know if my question is in some way right about consistency of version. I'll upgrade to SP1 from "newer" latest CU and then install SSIS, your information about post SP1 CU were useful. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answer for this question from member of Microsoft Technet called Lydia Zhang:

> ...SSIS will inherit the patch level that your installation media contains, which has no impact on the patch level of your existing SQL Server 2014 failover cluster instance...
>   https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/83f5eef4-bf7a-439e-8e6c-a3124434b12d/post-installation-of-ssis-for-existing-mssql-instance-with-different-build-versions?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade

So my question is resolved.